# SFML Не могу понять, почему не работает событие

Tags: события, sfml

```
window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false); //события выполнятся один раз, при нажатие на M
    Event castFireball;//каст первого заклинания (fireball)
    while (window.pollEvent(castFireball)) {
        if (castFireball.type == Event::KeyPressed) {
            if (castFireball.key.code == Keyboard::M) {
                player.mp -= fireball.manaCost;
                //Способность 1
                fireball.setAbility(player);
                //вправо
                if (player.dir == 0) { //направление 
                    fireball.dir = 0;
                }
                if (player.dir == 1) {
                    fireball.dir = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

всё компилируется нормально, но при нажатии ничего не происходит, а хотелось бы, чтобы объекту fireball задавалось одно из двух направлений. player - это объект, что передаётся конструктору fireball (игрок, что это заклинание скастовал) 
Ниже - метод класса Ability (fireball - объект класса ability)

```
    void setAbility(Player &player) { //поставить шар перед игроком
    x = player.x + player.w; 
    y = player.y + player.h / 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что я второй раз в теле программы вызываю window.pollevent - это оказалось неудачным решением. Теперь, когда я сделал так:

```
while (window.isOpen())
{
    Event event;
    window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false); //убрали периодический повтор вызова шара
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) 
        switch (event.type) {
            case Event::Closed:
                window.close();
            break;

                // нажатие клавиши
            case Event::KeyPressed:
                if (event.key.code == Keyboard::M) {
                   player.mp -= fireball.manaCost;
                  //Способность 1
                  fireball.setAbility(player);
                  //вправо
                  if (player.dir == 0) { //направление 
                    fireball.dir = 0;
                  }
                  //влево
                  if (player.dir == 1) {
                    fireball.dir = 1;
                  }
                }
            break;
        }
//... здесь продолжение (пока открыто окно).
```

Всё работает, как мне хотелось. Я очень надеюсь на то, что есть какие-то другие варианты и кто-то сведущий в SFML и плюсах в целом сможет мне помочь переработать эту галиматью ))